# Javascript/jQuery loop number with half increment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create loop number but with increment `0.5`

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i < i++){
  var newOption = $('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+' Minute</option>');
  $('.duration').append(newOption);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="duration"></select>
```

What I expected is like this:

1
1.5
2
2.5
3
3.5

So on until `10`

Any idea how to do the trick?

Comment: Why are do you have `i <` before `i++`? That part of the for loop isn't a condition, it's just code to execute after each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `i+= 0.5` like this:

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i+= 0.5){
  var newOption = $('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+' Minute</option>');
  $('.duration').append(newOption);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="duration"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `i+= 0.5` in the last part of loop.

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i+= 0.5) {
 console.log(i)
}
```

A `for` loop has 3 parts:

```
for ([initialExpression]; [conditionExpression]; [incrementExpression])
 statement
```

When a for loop executes, the following occurs:

- The initializing expression **initialExpression**, if any, is executed. This expression usually initializes one or more loop counters, but the syntax allows an expression of any degree of complexity. This expression can also declare variables.
- The **conditionExpression** expression is evaluated. If the value of **conditionExpression** is true, the loop statements execute. If the value of condition is false, the for loop terminates. (If the condition expression is omitted entirely, the condition is assumed to be true.)
  The statement executes. To execute multiple statements, use a block statement ({ ... }) to group those statements.
- If present, the update expression **incrementExpression** is executed.
  Control returns to Step 2.

So you can set any `incrementExpression` you want, like `+= 0.5` or anything else.

[Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)